# Calculate the number of zeros in square of ((4404 with base 17)) . ..?

Tags: number-theory

> Q Calculate the number of zeros in square of (4404 with base 17)?

My approach:

@Edit

is it right?

(4404 at base 17)*(4404 at base 17)=(10G0GF0G at base 17)
So, the number of zeros will be 3.

Comment: My guess: Calculate $4404^2$ on base $17$, then count the number of zeros. Though it is not really clear whether $4404$ is given on base $10$ or on base $17$. And it is not really clear whether the result should be taken on base $10$ or on base $17$.

Comment: May be the $4402^2$ is with base 17 and the ans can be in decimal or base 17 i need to check through options since the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you have $3$ conceivable ways for interpreting this question:

- Count the number of zeros in $((4404_{17})^2)_{17}$
- Count the number of zeros in $((4404_{17})^2)_{10}$
- Count the number of zeros in $((4404_{10})^2)_{17}$

Comment: (4404 at base 17)*(4404 at base 17)=(10G0GF0G at base 17)
So, the number of zeros will be 3.
I got this when i used ur first approach